# Objective-C calling upon a IBAction without having to change the sender to nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

I have a program that I would like to call upon another IBAction in a IBAction. However, the way I got it to work used [self buttonPress:nil]; which called upon the IBAction button as though it was a function but the problem was that the IBAction that I called upon sender's instance turned to nil so if anything in the IBAction that was called upon used sender it simply wouldn't do anything. Is there a way to call a IBAction without changing the instance of the sender?

Comment: just call the second action with the `sender` of the first `IBAction`!

Comment: Are you using the `sender` parameter inside the `buttonPress` function? If not then just remove the parameter from it in the method implementation. It isn't needed. You'll have to connect the IBAction again though.

Comment: I am using both sender in both my IBActions. And when i call upon one or the other I want the sender to work just as though someone actually touched it. I even tried [self button1Press:self] because I thought it would return an instance of itself to itself but the complier ran an error once I touched the button. I appreciate the help though fogmeister I should have specified more in my description that I want to use the senders to return an instance of sender to itself or an entirely different calling method. In short my bad

Comment: @luk2302 has the whole answer (and should probably post it as an answer). Just pass `sender` from one IBAction to the next.

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround "could" be to have your @IBAction methods serve as wrapper around different methods.  That way when you want to call another @IBAction you are actually calling the method it wraps.

```
@IBACTION Function1 {
  // Calls method:
  subMethod1()
}


@IBACTION Function2 {
  // Calls method:
  subMethod2()
}

@IBACTION Function3 {
  // Calls method:
  subMethod1()
  subMethod2()
}
```

Comment: Sweet thank you i will try to do that instead of dealing with the sender promblem. Thanks man!